# Sentencia if no se ejecuta como yo esperaba en Django

Tags: django

Tengo la siguiente funcion:

```
def destroy(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    id_act = kwargs.get('pk', None)
    userObject = User.objects.get(pk=self.request.user.pk)
    try:
        ocurrencia = Ocurrencia.objects.get(pk=id_act)
        if ComprobarPermisos.es_creador(ocurrencia, userObject) or ComprobarPermisos.es_jefe(ocurrencia,
                                                                                             userObject):
            repeticion = Repeticion.objects.get(ocurrencia=ocurrencia)
            if repeticion.__isnull== True:
                self.perform_destroy(ocurrencia)
                return Response({'Actividad eliminada'}, status=status.HTTP_301_MOVED_PERMANENTLY)
            else:
                evento = ocurrencia.event
                Ocurrencia.objects.filter(event_id=evento.pk).delete()
                self.perform_destroy(evento)
                return Response({'Actividad eliminada'}, status=status.HTTP_301_MOVED_PERMANENTLY)
        else:
            return Response({'Usted no puede ejecutar esta operacion'}, status=HTTP_403_FORBIDDEN)
    except Http404:
        return Response({'Not Found'}, status=status.HTTP_404_NOT_FOUND)
```

Mi problema es el siguente: Estoy haciendo un test para probar esta funcion y mi "escenario" es que `repeticion = Repeticion.objects.get(ocurrencia=ocurrencia)` falle. O sea, si no hay una repeticion se debe ejecutar lo que viene en el else. Cuando ejecuto el test el if falla pero no se ejecuta lo que viene en el else. Alguna idea de que puede estar sucediendo?

Comment: Cual es el If que te esta fallando!?

Comment: Es este: 
repeticion = Repeticion.objects.get(ocurrencia=ocurrencia)
 if repeticion.__isnull== True:

Comment: podrias, despues de cargar la variable "repeticion" hacerle un print("Print: " + repeticion.atributo) para saber que esta devolviendo algo? si no se ejecuta ese print, es probable que sea el if anterior el problema...

Comment: Ya he hecho print y no devuelve nada para la repeticion, para ocurrencia si lo hace. El if anterior se ejecuta sin problemas (el de las comprobaciones). Y para mi escenario se supone que repeticion sea null.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En el caso de que Repeticion.objects.get(ocurrencia=ocurrencia) falle, no te devuelve un objeto "null" te devuelve un error DoesNotExist.

Seguramente lo que se está ejecutando es el except y al estar limitado a  Http404 simplemente prosigue con la ejecución.

Prueba esto:

```
try:
    go = Repeticion.objects.get(ocurrencia=ocurrencia)
    //codigo si ha encontrado el registro
except Repeticion.DoesNotExist:
    //codigo si NO ha encontrado el registro
```

Comment: Mil gracias! efectivamente ese era el problema